# What is the process of this code, and why is the answer 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am having my first ever Python exam this Monday, and am naturally very nervous!
I am currently going through some old exams and this question appeared:

"What result of the following code will appear on the terminal?"

```
x = [1, "two", 3, "four", 5, "six"]
(x+x)[x[2]:x[2] + x[4]][(x+x)[8]]
```

I tested it, and the answer is 1. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around why. If anyone would be kind enough to explain the logic here that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> x = [1, "two", 3, "four", 5, "six"]
>>> (x+x)[x[2]:x[2] + x[4]][(x+x)[8]]
1
```

Now this can be broken into steps. First we concatenate `x` with itself, this will produce a new list:

```
>>> (x+x)
[1, 'two', 3, 'four', 5, 'six', 1, 'two', 3, 'four', 5, 'six']
```

This is by the way the same as `x * 2` or `2 * x`.

Now, naturally, `x[2]` is the element at index 2, or `3`, and `x[4]` is `5`. `x[2] + x[4]` evaluates to `8`.

Now we slice the concatenated list by elements `[3:8]`, getting indices 3...7 of the original:

```
>>> (x+x)[x[2]:x[2] + x[4]]
['four', 5, 'six', 1, 'two']
```

And finally we index this list again using `(x + x)[8]` - this will return the element at index 8 of the concatenated list which is 3. This is used to select the element at index 3 of the list from the previous step which is the number `1` between `six` and `two`...

Comment: @aymamoron in that case you might consider [*accepting my answer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)